# Best way to keep Identity data synchronized over microservices?

Tags: c#, architecture, microservices, identityserver4, gateway

We have implemented an architecture as follow:

1. Identity server 4: we use it as an authentication/authorization service, we have two internal clients, users gets redirected on Identity to login/register.
2. Ocelot API Gateway: is a simple gateway, this, Identity and the two frontend clients are our only services exposed directly to the web. Our frontend calls the gateway that act as some sort of proxy for our microservices. It also check the authorization of the user.
3. Microservices: behind this Gateway there are 6 microservices that obviously takes care of various things. One of this microservices take care of the users information.

Now our problem is that whenever an user register on Identity we send a message through rabbit to update the user microservice. But we also need to do the opposite: whenever an user update his name or lastname we have to change it in the users microservices and notify identity.

What's the best practice regarding this kind of issue?

We were thinking of just keep identity listening over a queue in rabbit but this would means that the flow of information from identity would be bidirectional and that might be a problem.

We were also thinking of changhing the "receiptor" of the "update profile" message sending it to identity that eventually will update name and lastname and forward the information via rabbit to our microservice but this would mean that:

1. Identity would receive a huge payload and would effectively use just two fields of that payload.
2. This method would not be behind the gateway anymore.

We were also thinking of just don't care about name and last_name saved in identity and completely remove them from the DB in identity.

What's your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is the following:

You could add a username claim to the access token. Then each service that receives the access token will compare it against its own database and update if it differs. This way you don't need any separate background communication between the services. Keep it simple!

Comment: That's a cool idea but it doesn't resolve the problem of changin name and lastname. From the client side i should be able to do it but to do so i should update the access token that is obviously not possible unless i contanct my identity server again. Also this would still means that some dbs will be out of sync until someone made a call to them. And this also prevent one person to change other people name and last name.

Comment: Pehaps take one step back and ask yourself if this is really a problem that the name is slightly different across services? I mean when is it important? When a user place an order, you can include the customer name in the order and then remember that. Inbetween orders, do you really care if the name is 100% same everywhere?  Do the services even need to know the name?